# how can I use SecurTrac for Domino to trigger agents?

Tags: lotus-domino

Can I configure SecurTrac to trigger an agent when a document is created or updated? SecurTrac is capturing the logs, but I want to trigger an agent to process the logs.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project on OpenNTF called [TriggerHappy](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Trigger%20Happy) that is specifically designed to trigger agents on events like creation or update of a document. It can work independently of SecurTrac.

Answer (score 0):

A Lotus Domino Agent support the "After documents are created or modified" as seen [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/fbb81e4de19d75ce85256c54004b7f3a?OpenDocument). So why couldn´t that be used?